# RTSP URL without mount point

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I have created RTSP server using gst-rtsp-server.
My requirement is to create a rtsp url looking like : rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554
I see that as per gstreamer rtsp server documentation. mount point cannot be empty.
But the rtsp client to be connected to the server cannot be modified to add mount point as its used in multiple areas.

Any suggestion how I can fulfill this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In gstreamer binaries 1.18.x, setting server mount point as '/' and client rtsp url as rtsp://serverip:port OR rtsp://serverip:port/ returns error : no media found.
This has been fixed in 1.19.1 binaries.